# List of installed repositories (yum)

Tags: yum, repository

In centos how can I get a list of installed repositories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just type  `yum repolist`  and you should output similar to

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * updates: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
repo id                                               repo name                                                        status
base                                                  CentOS-6 - Base                                                  6,346
extras                                                CentOS-6 - Extras                                                    4
updates                                               CentOS-6 - Updates                                                 751
repolist: 7,101
```

Comment: I installed Remi repository as explained in http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ But why it is not shown in the list?

Answer (score 2):

You can find them here: `/etc/yum.conf`